# DD-WRT Passing IP to a routed IP

Tags: windows, router

I'm using DD-WRT to route website traffic from my router to a webserver.

Basically, the setup goes NS -> localip -> my router -> external webserver.

However, all the info on the external server is comming from localip.  I want it to presist the info from the original request.

Is there a way to do this with DD-WRT? or possibly even on the webserver?  The web server is a Windows 2k8r2 server.

Thanks.

Comment: HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR seems like it's what i want to set.  The issue is, the site that it is hitting is getting all the same IP addresses, all from the router that fowarded it.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the server to reflect these changes:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/218180

Comment: what part of it lol...  there's like 10 parts, none for IIS7.